# Extract object's functions to global functions

Tags: php

So I have this class:

```
class MyClass {
    public static function printMessage($text) {
        echo $text;
    }
}
```

And I would like to use it in these ways:

```
MyClass::printMessage('test'); // test
printMessage('test'); // test
```

So `printMessage` will work as a method and also as a function. Is something like that possible with PHP? (Something like autoload for classes) I cannot find a good solution or even answer - `no`. It is not necessary for me, I'm just curious so I don't need to write same function structure twice. I know I can use code like `public static function printMessage($text) { return printMessage($text); }`, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you don't define it as a global function: no, you cannot call it as a global function.

Comment: But what speaks against using `MyClass::printMessage('test');` in the global scope?

Comment: You could use a `define` statement for such thing, but again: _why_?

Comment: `Is something like that possible with PHP?` Nope, how should php know what class to use for the method? The method name can be defined in many classes, thing about it.

Comment: Ok, as I said - I was just curious... So thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can map/wrap your class function into global function:

```
function printMessage($string){
    MyClass::printMessage($string);
}
```

But `Is something like that possible with PHP?` Nope. 
A function call MUST be unique in PHP.

You can also do this:

```
$printMessage = function($string ){MyClass::printMessage($string);};
```

to get an shorthand `$printMessage($string);`

But best is to avoid global functions overall. 
And if you are going next level coding, then static class methods should avoided too.

Comment: I thought about writing this answer, but all this is is the inverse of what's at the end of the question. I don't think that's what the OP wants

Comment: @Machavity Yep, i noted the wired stuff at the end of the Q too late. BUT, im not the last one ;)))

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a wrapper:

```
public function printMessage($text){
    MyClass::printMessage($text);
}
```

Or declare the function as global, which does not seem to be what you're looking for.